# How to dump parsed JWT token in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm writing an API in .NET Core that parses a JWT token that has been issued by `Keycloak`.

This token is very varied. Custom cliams are present with different types of data formats and nestings.

I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` as the NuGet dependency for this purpose and I would like to have the following controller to dump the incoming token:

```
[HttpGet]
public object Dump(string token)
{
   // token is what I have taken from the `Authorizaiton: Bearer token` HTTP header
   // How can I find out how .NET parses this token? I want the object model. I want the parsed token here.
}
```

How can I get this?

Comment: Can you share how does the `token` value looks like?

Comment: JWT token is a string which you can split by `.`. The first part is header, second is payload and third is Signature... the individual parts you can further base64 decode and that will give you JSON string and that you can store or deserialize to respective class object.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` class's [`ValidateToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.identitymodel.tokens.jwt.jwtsecuritytokenhandler.validatetoken#System_IdentityModel_Tokens_Jwt_JwtSecurityTokenHandler_ValidateToken_System_String_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Tokens_TokenValidationParameters_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Tokens_SecurityToken__) method, which returns a `ClaimsPrincipal` containing the token's claims.

Comment: I looked at that method, and it takes a bunch of parameters. I have already configured .NET to parse this token. What I want is **to see the parsed model** and dump it to a log file.

Comment: For example, the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` returns true or false based on the validity of the token. I want something like `HttpContext.ParsedToken`. Keycloak has `keycloak.js` which has two properties: `keycloak.token` and `keycloak.parsedToken`. The second one gives you the object model of the token.